# Python if statement and assignment

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I am working with BeautifulSoup in Python to parse some XML. I find myself having to write code that looks like this

```py
for document in soup.find_all('document'):
    if document.find('doc-number'):
        doc_number = document.find('doc-number').string
    # More similar if statements further down
```

I find writing the `document.find('doc-number')` twice: once in the `if` statement and once within the `if` block rather cumbersome and leading to long lines of code.

Is there a way I can make the code shorter and more Pythonic ?

This is Python 3.6

Comment: Which version of Python? You could use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) in 3.8.

Comment: oh okay, Yes. Removed!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I added the version of Python to the question

Comment: Then you can either extract a variable for the maybe-element (`el = document.find('doc-number')`) or a function (you could call like `doc_number = get_string_from('doc-number')`).

Answer (score 1):

From python 3.8,

```
for document in soup.find_all('document'):
    if (doc := document.find('doc-number')) is not None:
        doc_number = doc.string
```

These are called assignment expressions.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Edit: You just updated the python version to be 3.6, For versions less than 3.8, @jonrsharpe comment is the better answer